# Convert a File Object to Bitmap

Tags: java, android, caching, bitmap, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal-Image-Loader and there is this functionality that access the file cache of the image from sd card. But I don't know how to convert the returned file cache into bitmap. Basically I just wanted to assign the bitmap to an ImageView.

```
File mSaveBit = imageLoader.getDiscCache().get(easyPuzzle);

Log.d("#ImageValue: ", ""+mSaveBit.toString());
mImageView.setImageBitmap(mSaveBit);
```

Error: *"The method setImageBitmap(Bitmap) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (File)"*

Comment: use bitmapfactory to create bitmap from file

Comment: @PulkitSethi Can you show me how to do that, not sure of this. most examples uses path string of the image. In my case I am using the file itself.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You should be able to use `BitmapFactory`:

```
File mSaveBit; // Your image file
String filePath = mSaveBit.getPath();  
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I got error: The method decodeFile(String) in the type BitmapFactory is not applicable for the arguments (File)

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry, missed the `getPath()` method.

Comment: @Karl Please add description when  answering questions so that everybody can understand your answer, i.e. here, what is type of `filePath`, `mSaveBit`, it can be known from the question but still its a good habbit, well good answer (upvoted).

Comment: returning null in android 10

Answer (score 17):

1. Define File

   ```
   String fileName = "/myImage.jpg";
   File file = new File(fileName);
   ```
2. get Bitmap of Image

   ```
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
   ```
3. Set Bitmap to ImageView

   ```
   myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to get Bitmap from file path

```
fun getBitmap(filePath:String):Bitmap?{
    var bitmap:Bitmap?=null
    try{
        var f:File = File(path)
        var options = BitmapFactory.Options()
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(FileInputStream(f),null,options)
    }catch (e:Exception){

    }
    return bitmap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code to create a scaled image for ImageView in this case
 - Width:400
 - Height:400

```
final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"b.jpg");
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
img.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()),400,400,false));
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin Version

```
  if (requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST){
            if (data!=null){
                selectedfileUri=data.data
                if (selectedfileUri!=null && !selectedfileUri!!.path.isEmpty()){
                    val file = FileUtils.getFile(context,selectedfileUri)
                    val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.path)
                    uimg!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the right question, but if you use flag .cacheInMemory() in ImageLoader setup you can retrive the bitmap without need of recreate at any time using BitmapFactory to safe memory usage .

Just use:

Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache()·get("url as key");